# Elasticsearch with symfony - Error populate command softdeletable entity

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, soft-delete, foselasticabundle

I use the symfony bundle **Foselasticabundle** and i am facing a problem.

I have an entity (B) which can be deleted via gedmo softdeleteable.

I created the mapping, via the YAML file, and when I execute the following command **fos:elastica:populate** i get an error.

***Entity of type 'App\Entity\B' for IDs id(XX) was not found***

In fact, value was previously deleted in my database...

I would have liked him to insert an empty value in the field

Do you have a solution?

Thank you for your answers

```
fos_elastica.yaml

  clients:
    default: { url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%/' }

  indexes:
    app:
      types:
        A:
          properties:
            id: ~
            name: ~
            B:
              type: object
              id: ~
          persistence:
            driver: orm
            model: App\Entity\A
```

Comment: I have the same problem, any update?